# Azure Event Hub/Azure Function - Singleton

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

Is it possible for an Azure Function to read messages from an Azure Event Hub by a single thread?

I'm trying to perform in-order processing as the article below shows but I think a second Azure Function thread is picking up event hub message data causing data issues.

https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428

Comment: As explained in the article, Azure Function has no notion of order, the order comes from your Hub partitions.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I've only got 1 Event Hub partition set up so I'm not sure how there can be multiple threads running but that appears to be the behavior.

Comment: @RichardButterwood Have you tried the method in last paragraph **Triggering in ordered batches**? The article talks about setting [`maxBatchSize` to 1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#hostjson-settings) to avoid concurrent behavior but recommends the ordered batches for performance consideration.

Comment: I do use the MaxBatchSize option.  I think when the Azure Function determines it is getting overloaded it creates another thread which is normal behavior for Azure Functions that are on the consumption plan.

Answer (score 1):

> when the Azure Function determines it is getting overloaded it creates another thread which is normal behavior for Azure Functions that are on the consumption plan.

Your assumption is basically right, as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#how-the-consumption-plan-works) says,

> scale controller automatically scales CPU and memory resources by adding additional instances of the Functions host, based on the number of events that its functions are triggered on

But I also see the [tutorial](https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/in-order-event-processing-with-azure-functions-bb661eb55428) along with the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#trigger---scaling) mentions

> a single partition will only have a lease on one processor host at a time. That means multiple function instances can’t pull messages from the same partition.

Hence setting [maxBatchSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#host-json) to 1 is supposed to avoid concurrent in single partition reading.

If this doesn't guarantee the singleton, I suggest you add [WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#websitemaxdynamicapplicationscaleout)
 with value `1` in Application settings to ensure no more host instances will be created.

Comment: I thought maxBatchSize was the number messages retrieved in a batch from the event hub?  That is the behavior I've seen.

I want the same behviour as the Azure Function maxConcurrentCalls setting?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1

    "serviceBus": {
      "maxConcurrentCalls": 16,
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "autoRenewTimeout": "00:05:00"
    },

Comment: @RichardButterwood Yes, and the trigger processes the batch of messages concurrently when the trigger is bound to single EventData(instead of batch EventData[]), similar to maxConcurrentCalls of service bus trigger. So setting maxBatchSize to 1 is to read one message a time. Have you tried to add `WEBSITE_MAX_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_SCALE_OUT` to restrict the instance count?

Comment: Hi Jerry.  Thanks for the message.  I did add it but my original issue continues.  Now I think it wasn't related to function spinning up additional instances.

Comment: @RichardButterwood Sorry I came back late. Could you check whether the configuration of maxBatchSize fits your function runtime? [v1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json-v1#eventhub) and [v2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-event-hubs#hostjson-settings) have different formats.

Comment: Hi Jerry.  I understand that changing maxBatchSize to 1 would force it to read one message at a time but would that stop the multi-threading?  Also, I set the maxBatchSize to 300 for performance reasons.  Would changing it to 1 impact performance?  Thank you for your help!

Comment: @RichardButterwood, setting the maxBatchSize to 1 will stop the multi-threading issue at a cost of performance.